# Meaning of the * in nuget 4.6.2

Tags: nuget

What is meaning of the * wildcard in the nuget 4.6.2

```
   <PackageReference Include="Autofac">
      <Version>*</Version>
    </PackageReference>
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`PackageReference` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) in turn refers to the [package versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards) documentation, which includes:

> When using the PackageReference format, NuGet also supports using a wildcard notation, `*`, for Major, Minor, Patch, and pre-release suffix parts of the number. Wildcards are not supported with the packages.config format.

The documentation is a little unclear when it comes to pre-releases:

> Pre-release versions are not included when resolving version ranges. Pre-release versions are included when using a wildcard (`*`). The version range `[1.0,2.0]`, for example, does not include 2.0-beta, but the wildcard notation `2.0-*` does.

My experience is that it *will* pick up pre-releases when the wildcard is after a dash, but not before.

As a worked example, at the time of writing, xunit has version `2.3.1` and `2.4.0-beta.1.build3958`. Here's the results I get:

```
Version attribute           Version installed
*                           2.3.1
2.*                         2.3.1
2.4.*                       Error
2-*                         2.0.0
2.4.0-*                     2.4.0-beta.1.build3958
```

Comment: I would like to get the highest version of the package that is available. How can I achieve this? dependency version highest seems not to work with PackageReference

Comment: @user656822: What you've got should already get the latest GA version. I think if you want the latest *prerelease* version, you need to know the major/minor version already, by the looks of it. So in your example, that should already be using Autofac 4.7.1.

Comment: This is not true for nuget version 4.6.2. In this version it will get lower posible , wich is  2.something

Comment: @user656822: Hmm... could you provide a complete project example we can experiment with? (I'm using .NET Core projects, where I restore with `dotnet restore`, and that works fine. With the huge variation in tools and file formats around, the more precise you can make the question, the easier it'll be to help you.)

Comment: You can test this behavior on new project, just add packageReference to csproj. nuget and try to resotre it using nuget restore. I think dotnet resote works like nuget before version 4.4.3  but new version of nuget  downloads lower version for * . To download newst pacage you have to give it version like this : "[*, )"

Comment: @user656822: What kind of project though? It would be a lot simpler if you'd add a sample project in the question rather than us guessing. (And put it into the question rather than just as a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is a wild card, as you specified. This means the package you're building needs some version of `Autofac`.